# how to speed up video and add watermark using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

How can we speed up video and add watermark using ffmpeg

for speed up video we have this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

for water mark we use

```
"-y", "-i", j, "-i", image1, "-i", image2, "-i", image3, "-filter_complex",
               "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,1,2)'[tmp];" +
                       "[tmp][2:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,7)'[tmp];"+
                       "[tmp][3:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,9,11)'",
                "-c:v","libx264",  "-preset", "ultrafast", out;
```

how can we merge bot commands I have various commands
like this

```
    ""-y", "-i", j, "-i", image2, "-i", image2, "-i", image2, "-filter_complex",
     "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" +
             "[1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,1,2)'[tmp];" +
                  "[tmp][2:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,7)'[tmp];"+
                    "[tmp][3:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,9,11)'",
            "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]", "-b:v", "2097k", "-r", "60", "-vcodec", "mpeg4",
              "-preset", "ultrafast", out"
```

how can we speed video and add watermark

the error that i get is

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xac59c530] No output pad can be associated to link label '1:v'.
Error initializing complex filters.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
"-y", "-i", j, "-i", image1, "-i", image2, "-i", image3, "-filter_complex",
               "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[m];" +
               "[m][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,1,2)'[tmp];" +
                       "[tmp][2:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,7)'[tmp];"+
                       "[tmp][3:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,9,11)';"  +
                       "[0:a]atempo=2.0",
                "-c:v","libx264",  "-preset", "ultrafast", out;
```

Comment: can we use any other codec than`libx264`, if i am correct it has copy right issues, i tried `"-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac"` but it didnot work ,

Comment: No copyright issues, but possible royalties. See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/14699/1871 `-c:v mpeg4 -q:v 7` will also work but not necessary.